# iOS 7 seems to be killing apps too often

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 7.  I've noticed a pattern regarding apps "reloading" or starting back up from where they were after switching to another app and back.
On previous versions of IOS, I noticed that apps would sometimes reload after window switching, but it seemed to me to be somewhat random, and somewhat based upon which app I was originally running.  For example, if I was playing Angry Birds, I knew that it would take the phone powering off or a really long time even switching between apps before it would have to reload; however with Scrabble - it seemed like I could answer a text message and the app would restart and ask me to log back in.

With iOS 7, this behavior seems different and completely predictable.  No matter what app I am using, if I switch to mobile Safari, that app will need to reload - even if only 2 seconds have passed, but I can switch to any other app, or do anything else short of powering off the phone, and the app I returned to would start where I left off.  Switching to Safari forces any other app to reload when switching-every time.

Can anyone confirm this?
Is it a function of something I can control?
What is it a function of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**iOS will kill apps if it needs to.**

There's not really much you can do about it, without jailbreaking. iOS will automatically manage an app's memory, and will kill an app if another app requests more memory. Also, apps using a large amount of CPU will cause iOS to kill other apps so that the foreground app always has the best experience.

If you find that it's killing apps more than it should be, try using apps with less memory usage. For example, try only opening one tab in Safari, then switch apps and switch back. It should be less likely to be terminated if it has less tabs open since there will be less memory usage.

For more information about multitasking, see:

- [iOS: Understanding multitasking](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211)

Comment: That makes sense.  Intuitively I know that more tabs should use more memory, but I thought Apple had come up with some wizardry to fix that.  Thanks

Comment: The biggest problem is that so many major third party apps don't even bother saving their state so that when they are killed they can at least restore themselves in some useful fashion. iOS 7 seems to use so much memory.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 phone calls that each lasted about an hour or more, and backing up, erasing, resetting to factory, rinse and repeat several times, the answer I got from a senior apple tech was not encouraging.

He says that ios7 stores more info per app than ios6 did. But the cache memory (being hardware) is still the same size, and now the same amount of apps can't fit in the cache.

Sometimes larger apps will cause multitasking to dump every other app in the cache. Try running Clash of Clans.

Try doing a hard restart. This will give you a little more room in your multitasking cache, but it will only last a half a day before you can only multitask 3 or 4 apps at a time again