# How can I keep an app open in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, multitasking

As I was using an app on my iPhone, I accidentally hit the home button. I quickly reopened the app. But instead of it resuming where I left off, the app had to load all over again. (This was Clash of Clans and I was in a raid!)

Is there a way to keep an app open in the background?

Such a feature would also allow me to quickly check something and then return to the app that I was on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apps are paused when backgrounded and resume when opened. If an app does not correctly resume to the state it was left in, this is something only the developer can fix.

It's not possible to run an app in the background as if it was in the foreground. Apps can only run a limited set of tasks in the background for a short period of time per Apple guidelines, or use structured backgrounding such as Background App Refresh.

Also see [iOS 7 seems to be killing apps too often](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116906/ios-7-seems-to-be-killing-apps-too-often).

Comment: I think you should also add that if **Background App Activities** is disabled fully or for a specific app, apps may not function properly if they require internet connection and are in the "background.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on [iOS 9.0 - 9.1](https://canijailbreak.com/), you can [jailbreak with PanGu](http://en.pangu.io/). You can then install a tweak called [Dissident](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/org.thebigboss.dissident/) in Cydia that enables backgrounding with different behaviors per-application.

Answer (score -5):

From  [Background Refresh - How do I allow the app to run in the background?](https://support.hushed.com/hc/en-us/articles/200346675-Background-Refresh-How-do-I-allow-the-app-to-run-in-the-background-)

> #### For iOS Devices
>
> To enable this, there are 2 options to check :
>
> 1 - Low Power Mode (Settings App - > Battery - > Low Power Mode) needs
> to be off
>
> 2 - Background App Refresh (Settings App -> Hushed - > Background App
> Refresh needs to be ON
>
> If Background refresh is greyed out in the ON position, go To Settings
> App - > General - > Background App Refresh - > Turn on the option for
> the system, and then you can turn on / off by app.

Comment: Plagiarized from https://support.hushed.com/hc/en-us/articles/200346675-Background-Refresh-How-do-I-allow-the-app-to-run-in-the-background-